# Browser cannot find imported javascript package, generates error 404

Tags: javascript, webstorm, node-modules, livechat

I'm trying to build a webpage that imports and uses a JS package, following a [tutorial](https://developers.livechatinc.com/docs/agent-app-widgets/#developing-your-own-widget) for LiveChat. This says to import using

`import LiveChat from '@livechat/agent-app-widget-sdk';`

However that results in this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@livechat/agent-app-widget-sdk". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I thought by starting with a "/" this should be fixed, but then I get this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I've tried a couple of different ways of referencing the package (including "node_modules" and using the full path to the main JS file, agentapp-widget.cjs.js). There's no doubt I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. The files in Webstorm:

[image]

HTML file:

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.livechatinc.com/boilerplate/1.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<br>
<form class="form">
    <label class="form__label" for="claimid">
        <input type="number" style="" class="form__input" id="claimid">
    </label>
    <button class="button yellow" type="button" onclick="addToClaims()">
        <span>Sla op</span>
    </button>
</form>

<div class="container">
    <h4>Claim ID's</h4>
    <div id="claims">

    </div>
</div>

<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS file:

```js
import LiveChat from '/@livechat/agent-app-widget-sdk';

function addToClaims() {
    
}

function removeFromClaims(element) {
    
}

window.onload = function() {
    LiveChat.init();
};
```

Can someone tell me if this is a Webstorm configuration issue, a mistake in the referencing or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@livechat/agent-app-widget-sdk` library is published in format only suitable for being used in Node.js ecosystem; you can't load it in browser using the new ES6 `<script type="module">`.
See https://salomvary.com/es6-modules-in-browsers.html#using-external-dependencies for more info on this